# How can I fix my code to do line by line conditional statements in Matlab

Tags: matlab, conditional-statements

I just started learning Matlab roughly an hour ago after being told I had to convert my rscript into Matlab. I wrote a conditional statement below and it does not work. The reason I believe is because it is not currently going line by line. data is a Matlab table. Here is my current code:

```
if data.Year == data.initYear
    data.initY = -1
else
    data.initY = 0
end
```

in R it was:

```
workable$saleYear <- ifelse(workable$year == workable$initYear, -1,0)
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What does `it does not work` mean? What is the size and type of your variables? Without a [functioning example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) nobody is going to have any idea how to help you. Use [MATLAB's debugger](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/debugging-process-and-features.html) to step through your code and investigate the values of your variables.

Comment: And what do you mean with `line by line`? Are you processing a file?

Comment: I am trying to do this operation for each row of my table. For each row I want matlab to compare data.initYear to data.Year

Comment: If every element in `data.Year` equals `data.initYear` it will go into the if statement. If both are scalars, it will of course mean they are equal. If it is a vector/matrix, a single incorrect element will force it into `else`. However, vectors in if statements are ugly, so if `data.Year` is a vector you should use `all`. If the code does not do what is expected you have a problem that the values assigned to `data.Year` or `data.initYear` is incorrect. I have no idea why you use a table (never found it useful), but I assume that you have a good reason to.

Answer (score 0):

You want to do this in a vector. That way you don't need `for` loops or `if` statements.

```
data.initY = zeros(size(data.Year));
data.initY(data.Year == data.initYear) = -1;
```